# Why the program returns an empty list when I use lxml to get information in a website

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, lxml

I want to get the column "Name of Menber" in website http://164.100.47.132/LssNew/Members/Alphabaticallist.aspx , so what I want the program returns is a list of "Adhalrao Patil,Shri Shivaji..", but I get an empty list. Xpath is verified in Firepath, so I just don't know what's wrong. 
Here is my code:

```
import urllib
from lxml import etree

result =   urllib.urlopen("http://164.100.47.132/LssNew/Members/Alphabaticallist.aspx")
html = result.read()

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(html), parser)
print type(tree)
xpath = ".//* [@id='ctl00_ContPlaceHolderMain_Alphabaticallist1_dg1']/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[position()=3]/a/text()"
filtered_html = tree.xpath(xpath)

print filtered_html
```

and it returns:

```
[]
```

However, when I use another xpath:

```
.//*[@id='ctl00_ContPlaceHolderMain_Alphabaticallist1_dg1_ctl02_Hyperlink2']
```

I can get the value of the first column:

```
[Adhalrao Patil,Shri Shivaji]
```

The two xpath are both verified in firepath, Why the former cannot work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that some tags, like `<tbody>` are filtered out from the `html` code read by `lxml`, so try without it, like:

```
xpath = ".//* [@id='ctl00_ContPlaceHolderMain_Alphabaticallist1_dg1']/tr[position()>1]/td[position()=3]/a/text()"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your xpath can work. And can I ask another question? Do you have a proper way to see the whole html code filtered by lxml?

Comment: @QM.py: I use the `View Page Source` of my browser. Also the [scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)